# PHP Data Objects Fetching A Fields Name From A Table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How would I fetch the name of all the fields in a table of a database using PHP Data Objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to do this you have to query the db schema.  In MySQL, there is a system generated database called information_schema.

from within it, you could run:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'desired_table'
AND table_schema = 'database_name'
```

Comment: I also have a lot of databases with tables that have a certain tablename e.g. browers.. and it returns all of that data..

Comment: SELECT column_name
FROM COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'desired_table'
AND table_schema = 'database_name'